# Loop through dynamic template parameters in Azure devops YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I want to perform some actions (publish) on an array of string which are passed as parameter.
The thing is, this parameter is dynamic :

```
# pipeline.yml

- job: MyJob
    pool:
      [...]
    steps:
      - pwsh: |
          $affected = ['app-one', 'app-two'] # Here I hardcoded the array but in my real code this is set dynamically
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=affected;isOutput=true]$affected"
        name: setAffected
        displayName: 'Settings affected'

- template: ./build.yml
  parameters:
    affected: $[ dependencies.Affected.outputs['setAffected.affected'] ] # Here I pass the array of string to the template
```

```
# build.yml

parameters:
  affected: ''

jobs:
  - job: Build
    condition: succeeded('Affected')
    dependsOn: Affected
    pool:
      [...]
    variables:
      affected: ${{ parameters.affected }}
    steps:
      - ${{each app in $(affected)}}:
          - pwsh: |
              Write-Host "${{app}}"
      - ${{each app in parameters.affected}}:
          - pwsh: |
              Write-Host "${{app}}"
```

Neither of `${{each app in $(affected)}}` or `${{each app in parameters.affected}}` work...
How can I manage to execute some actions on each of my array item?

Thanks

Comment: Let me guess. You wanted to run a mororepo app like Nx? I kind of wanted to do the exact same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Within a template expression, you have access to the parameters
>   context that contains the values of parameters passed in.
>   Additionally, you have access to the variables context that contains
>   all the variables specified in the YAML file plus the system
>   variables. **Importantly**, it doesn't have **runtime variable**s such
>   as those stored on the pipeline or given when you start a run.
>   Template expansion happens very early in the run, so those variables
>   aren't available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops